# How to navigate from a child Stack Navigator back to parent while resetting navigation stack at the same time, in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I've read countless react-navigation docs, and I know there is way to do this, but it's definitely what I would call non-trivial and definitely non-intuitive.

I have a root navigation stack:

```
export const NavigationStack = StackNavigator({
    Splash: {
        screen: Splash
    },
    Signup: {
        screen: Signup
    },
    Login: {
        screen: SignIn
    },
    ForgottenPassword: {
        screen: ForgottenPassword
    },
    Discover: {
        screen: Discover
    },
    ProfileShow: {
        screen: ProfileShow
    }
}, {
    headerMode: 'none'
})
```

The ForgottenPassword screen is a child Stack Navigator:

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import PasswordResetProcess from './index'

const ForgottenPassword = StackNavigator({
    ResetPassword: {
        screen: PasswordResetProcess
    }
}, {
        headerMode: 'none'
    })

export default ForgottenPassword
```

On that `index.js` Container Component, there is a sub-component that I pass navigation to, like this:

```
    switch (lastCompletedStep) {
        case NEW_RESET_REQUEST:
            return <InputTel navigation={navigation} />

        case INPUT_TEL:
            return <ResetPassword navigation={navigation} />
```

That `ResetPassword` component is the one in question. It triggers an action creator and passes `this.props.navigation` into the action creator:

```
await props.handleResetSubmit(token, props.navigation)
```

From inside this action creator, `props.navigation` is available as `navigation`. I can do this fine:

```
navigation.navigate('Discover') // see how this is from the root Navigation Stack
```

I cannot, however, do this:

```
navigation.dispatch({
    type: 'Navigation/RESET',
    index: 0,
    actions: [{ type: 'Navigate', routeName: 'Discover' }]
})
```

It throws this error:

[image]
[edit] I just tried this and it also generated the same error:

```
    navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Discover' })]
    }))
```

> How do I reset the stack while navigating to `Discover` from here?

I feel like the answer is to navigate to discover and reset the stack at the same time as some kind of child operation, but I don't know where to begin putting that together. The `react-navigation` documentation is horrendous for illustrating child to parent operations.

Here is my best guess at what it approximately has to look like:

```
navigation.dispatch({
    type: 'Navigation/NAVIGATE',
    routeName: 'Discover',
    actions: [{ type: 'Reset', index: 0, key: null }]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it with this code:

```
navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    key: null,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Discover' })]
}))
```

The secret was to add `key: null`, which I have seen people doing before. It is a very important element for times when you are resetting.

Here is the documentation I found that illustrates it:

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1127

I think this works because `NavigationActions` has knowledge of the root navigation stack, so it works for the same reason `navigation.navigate('Discover')` worked (in the context of my code in this question).

Answer (score 1):

in version >2 of react navigation, NavigationActions.reset() doesnt work.
You should use StackActions.reset() instead:

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';
const resetStackAction = StackActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Discover' })],
    });
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetStackAction);
```